# Unable to print images links using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, webdriver

AS i want to extract only image link but it create problem in printing from https://www.junaidjamshed.com/womens/stitched.html?product_list_limit=30

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from selenium import webdriver
url= "https://www.junaidjamshed.com/womens/stitched.html?product_list_limit=30"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('F:/chromedriver',options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(6)
pageSource = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find_all('li',class_='item product product-item') 
for items in content:
    image = items.find('img',{'class':'product-image-photo lazy'},src=True)
    print(image)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `css` selector.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.junaidjamshed.com/womens/stitched.html?product_list_limit=30")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

content = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser').select(".product-image-photo")
print("\n".join(i["data-origsrc"] for i in content))

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-028s_1_.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-016s_1_.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-018s_1_.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-017_1_.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-728s_1_.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-741_1__1.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/7/4/744_1_.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-748s_1_.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-749s_1_.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-742_1__1.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-747s_1_.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-740s_1_.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-745s_1_.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-743_1__1.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-177s_1_.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-718-.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-174s_1_.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-025_1__1.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-175s_1_.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-173s_1_.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-176s_1_.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-717-s.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-719_1__1.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-723_1__1.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-724s_1_.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-026.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-006s.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-010s_1_.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-020s_1_.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
https://www.junaidjamshed.com/media/catalog/product/2/1/21-021-.jpg?quality=80&bg-color=255,255,255&fit=bounds&height=755&width=589&canvas=589:755
```

Comment: it print only 3 links but i want to print whole page image link